# How to eliminate header for first page?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, headers

LibreOffice is putting a header on every page.

I'd like the header to be on all pages but the first page. Is this possible?

How do I make it so?

Answer (score 1):

The presence and properties of page headers in LibreOffice documents is associated with *page styles*; to have headers on some pages and not others requires using different page styles on different pages.

I did it this way, based on suggestions from http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/20712:

1. Move cursor to end of first page
2. "Insert" menu → "Manual Break..." → Page break, Style: Default Style
3. "Format" menu → "Title Page..." → Convert existing, at Document start, Style: First Page
4. Change margins on page 1 back to what I had before.

The documentation suggests it could be done better: https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Creating_and_Applying_Page_Styles

1. "Format" menu → "Title Page..." → Convert existing, at Document start, Style: First Page
2. "Format" menu → "Page..." → Organizer → make sure Name is "First Page" and Next Style is "Default Style"
3. Change margins etc. as needed.

(Using LibreOffice 4.2.6.3 on Mac OS X 10.10.2)

Answer (score 0):

Reference: Libreoffice Version: 4.1.3.2

In Libreoffice Writer:
Format --> Page ---> Header
there is a checkbox for header on
and below another checkbox with  ***same contenent on the first page***.

Comment: This seems to allow different header content on the first page, but still allocates space for the header on the first page; how does one make it so the first page doesn't have even an empty header?

Comment: I suppose this is another question... something like _"how to do a special page with margin/style different from the template?"_. Usually in a book or publication, the pages are with common margins, even for what it concerns the header and footer zones. There is still the possibility to have a special page (think e.g. the 1st page of a thesis). If you really want, you can change them manually, for example form the preview page,  and apply the modification only to the current page.

Answer (score 0):

"In Libreoffice Writer: Format --> Page ---> Header
there is a checkbox for header on and below another checkbox with same contenent on the first page."

Yeah, I have that set up that way, but it's still using the same header as left pages.

Comment: This has already been mentioned and it doesnt answer the question anyway.  Please read the tour on this site under the Help section.